# "bash xfce4.sh" gives syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Tags: linux, windows, unix, installation

When i try to run `bash xfce4.sh`, it gives me the error:
`xfce4.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token` <'
xfce4.sh: line 1: `<html><head><title>Loading...</title></head><body><script type='text/javascript'>window.location.replace('https://kali.sh/xfce4.sh?ch=1&js=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJKb2tlbiIsImV4cCI6MTY2NjkxMzIzMCwiaWF0IjoxNjY2OTA2MDMwLCJpc3MiOiJKb2tlbiIsImpzIjoxLCJqdGkiOiIyc2gwa2QwZW4xdWdicTlvaGMwdDRwb2EiLCJuYmYiOjE2NjY5MDYwMzAsInRzIjoxNjY2OTA2MDMwNzgyMDIxfQ.tN_1ZFHTKGGPtECn_V_PNJhsE8II0fcxWjYnZhB9evc&sid=1de40110-563e-11ed-ba81-f9449723c437');</script></body></html>'`

I have tried to install dos2unix and converted xfce4.sh to Unix format, but still gave the same problem.

Comment: Looks like you try to run a web page as shell script --- that doesn't work. There seems to be some JavaScript code in there to redirect you to an actual xfce4.sh script, maybe that code did not run? Did you disable JavaScript in your browser or download this via curl or such? Try to download again and make sure you get a shell script, not html.

Comment: yup, you are right! I got the .sh via wget, but it was from an outdated link from a youtube tutorial! thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run an HTML file as a bash script.

After you download the correct file, you also need to make it executable:

```
chmod +x xfce4.sh
```

Then execute it; you can also execute a script with:

```
./xfce4.sh
```

Assuming your current directory is the same as the script's directory.